# Automate concatenation

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate the concatenation with skipping the row if there is not value in cells.. 
example of what the result should be like in picture...
the colours are from where taken the numbers

[image]

Comment: What concatenation? Concatenation means `combining text values`.

Comment: i want this exact result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with SumProduct, like in the screenshot:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A8*B4:B8)*$B$1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but i need the background calculation to be shown

Comment: Then you can step through the calculation with Evaluate Formula. If you want it as text, just use IF statements and concatenate these.